# Kali Linux installation, dual boot with Windows 8

Tags: linux, boot, usb, unix, kali-linux

I have Windows 8 installed on my system, and I am trying to install Kali Linux using a bootable USB flash drive.

System details:

- 4 GB RAM
- Core i5 Processor
- Windows 8 64-bit

I have prepared a bootable USB flash drive with win32disk imager.

Currently I am able to boot live Linux from the USB, but when I try the *Graphical Install* option I am getting an illegible screen with visual artifacts.

[image: Graphical install Screenshot]

As I am able to boot live Linux it doesn't seem that ISO is corrupt. What can be another reason for this?

Should I proceed with Text install? if yes please suggest any link for the process as I am new with this OS.

Do I need an internet connection when installing Kali Linux?

Comment: Download Kali Linux from it's [official site](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) and match the sha256 hash from powershell. Also try [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to crate bootable media.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the installation of Kali much easier!  You just want to download the free **VirtualBox** *OR*  **Vmaware**  and o to this link:   https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/04/08/detailed-guide-installing-kali-linux-on-virtualbox/

With this link, you will learn what is VirtualBox, how to use it and how to install Kali Linux!

With  this program, you can install VIRTUAL Os's, that you can use it with your default Os.  For example,  you can use your Windows 8 and ***AT THE SAME TIME***, you can use Kali Linux through an app.

> Did I solve your question? If I do, PLEASE press the green check button, for
>   other users that has the same problem, to see my answer and help them!

Hope I helped!

Comment: I assume there are many tools in Kali that require direct access to the actual network interfaces. Running Kali in a VirtualBox will prevents this and make these tools unusable.

Comment: @xenoid Nop. I'm using Kali with the same program, I'm not having any network cards and I'm using it with ought any problem in all his programs...!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am looking to use it with dual boot. As i already have 4 gb ram it will be difficult with vmware.

Comment: @HarshJoshi ok. I didnt pay much attention in 4gb ram...   im having 16 and im running it very nice and smoothly..     For dual boot, i cant give you the best idea... Sorry. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

When installing linux distros always follow there official documentation related to installation.In your case you can go to [this link](https://docs.kali.org/category/installation)
You can go with graphical install from the start menu,once you have done the necessary partitions as explained in the given link.

Hope this helps and by the way welcome to the linux world.

Comment: I am referring the same link. But i am getting the blue screen(see image) when i choose graphical install

Comment: Then you can go with text install,there will not be much difference just less graphics.